# Are there filesystems which do not support mmap?

Tags: linux, mmap

I have seen advice that any time you want to use mmap(2) backed by a file, you should also provide read(2)/write(2)-based implementation, in case of ENODEV error (filesystem does not support mmap call).

I am designing a program which needs to access (in read-only mode) a very large data file (gigabytes), and mmap'ing it would be the easiest way. Read-based solution will be quite a lot of work. I am targeting somewhat recent 64-bit Linuxes. Are there modern filesystems which do NOT support mmap call?

I have heard that at some point ecryptfs, squashfs, vfat and NFS did not support mmap, but from looking at the kernel source, all of these filesystems support mmap just fine now.